# Sending an image from client to server over a socket connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, binary, hex

I wrote some code for converting an image to hex in the client side, and then the hex values are send to server. On the server side, this hex will be converted to binary and the binary values are written to a file. But I am not getting the same image. The resulting image is not visible at all.

**client side:**

```
with open('1.jpg',"rb") as f:

    contents = f.read()

    contentss = binascii.hexlify(contents)

    s.send(contentss)
```

**server side**:

```
data = c.recv(1024)

binary = binascii.unhexlify(data)

f = open('1server.jpg',"wb")

f.write(binary)
```

**EDIT**

If I am printing the "**binary**" using "print binary", then i am getting output as   ÿØÿà

what is happening here? please help.

Comment: It worked! When I used a large value instead of 1024, I got the same image. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing 1024(length of receiving data) with the length of sent data will resolve this issue.